# Vcc pin of 8051

Tags: microcontroller, 8051

I have tried to simulate a micro controller based project in Proteus, but I cannot see a Vcc pin of the 8051 micro controller. Is it inbuilt or something? I am using Atmel at89c51.

Answer (score 4):

The power pins are hidden in Proteus schematic capture because they are automatically connected to the VCC and GND nets. You can change the nets they are connected to by editing the component's properties (right-click on component, choose 'Edit Properties', then 'Hidden Pins').